# Sometimes docker container dns fail

Tags: networking, docker

Sometimes my docker container cannot resolve dns..

```
[root@1397f4b5b0b8 ~]# ping google.co.kr
ping: unknown host google.co.kr
```

While it works without problems after a week. Suddenly it causes problems.

Some informations.

1) docker container ip

```
160: eth0: <BROADCAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:a4:72:e5:a0:a4 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.4/16 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::14a4:72ff:fee5:a0a4/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
162: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

2) docker container result.conf

```
options timeout:1 attempts:1 rotate
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver 192.168.100.60
```

3) I sent ping to another container

```
[root@1397f4b5b0b8 ~]# ping 172.17.0.3
PING 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=1.01 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.060 ms
64 bytes from 172.17.0.3: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.033 ms
```

4) docker ip addr

```
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:4D:B5:ED:F2:9C  
          inet addr:172.17.42.1  Bcast:172.17.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc99:12ff:fe49:b968/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:10615013037 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:10581841163 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1452195292535 (1.3 TiB)  TX bytes:1436185782855 (1.3 TiB)

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr C8:1F:66:F9:22:1B  
          inet addr:192.168.100.64  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::ca1f:66ff:fef9:221b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18816069331 errors:0 dropped:4421 overruns:0 frame:69216
          TX packets:18985345996 errors:0 dropped:6 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2823201130099 (2.5 TiB)  TX bytes:2383729440082 (2.1 TiB)
          Interrupt:35 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:14689636131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:14689636131 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1541592592181 (1.4 TiB)  TX bytes:1541592592181 (1.4 TiB)
```

5) docker routing table

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
0.0.0.0         192.168.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
```

I take restart to docker and start container.
Then docker container can connect to the outside.

```
[root@1397f4b5b0b8 ~]# ping google.co.kr
PING google.co.kr (173.194.72.94) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from tf-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.72.94): icmp_seq=1 ttl=48 time=69.3 ms
64 bytes from tf-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.72.94): icmp_seq=2 ttl=48 time=69.4 ms
64 bytes from tf-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.72.94): icmp_seq=3 ttl=48 time=69.4 ms
64 bytes from tf-in-f94.1e100.net (173.194.72.94): icmp_seq=4 ttl=48 time=69.3 ms
```

How should I fix it?

Comment: I found dmesg log.
netlink: 20 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.
netlink: 20 bytes leftover after parsing attributes.

Comment: How about the host? Maybe you're just losing your network? What OS is the host running?

Comment: Centos 6.6, Host is okay when Problem situation. It is only cotainer fail network to outside..

Comment: This is beyond my knowledge. You could try setting the container network to "host", and see if that helps? https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#network-settings

Answer (score 1):

For some reason the `resolv.conf` permissions are too restricted. You can solve it with:

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/resolv.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the [Google public DNS FAQ](https://developers.google.com/speed/public-dns/faq#devsite_header_5) Google does not make any promise on the availability of their public DNS service (i.e. no SLA - Service Level Agreement). In other words it may fail at any time for random reasons and that's what you are experiencing.